# Wordpress: using posts from a older version in a fresh installed new one

Tags: wordpress, database-migration, posts

I have a Wordpress website (v 6.1.1) and I want to develop a new site with a fresh installation of Wordpress.
So that there is no interruption in the service, I want to install the new version of Wordpress in a directory on my server to work on the new site with no rush.

I want to keep the posts of the "Blog" section and for this I ask you: is there any way to export the posts from the old version to the new one?
I think on replacing the new wp_posts and wp_postmeta database tables with the old ones but I don't know if this is going to work or if this is a correct way to do it.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a staging site of the current site and update the WordPress version there.
you will get all old data on the updated version of WordPress.

Comment: thanks Ashok! but I need to start clean, the current site has been up for a long time and even working ok overall with v.6.1.1 is starting to have some glitches

Comment: Then you can export blogs and import.
https://prnt.sc/HlstDn4t1e3f
you can use WordPress default export import